# How to solve Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Tags: c#, mysql, exception

Ive been trying to find the solution regarding this error, I found some or something of similar posts here but it didnt solve my problem. I have  windows form application using .NET6 with multiple class library projects using also .NET6 as framework.

Whenever I try to INSERT an entry to the database, I get this following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
```

it happens whenever I reached the connection open:

```
public static void ExecuteNonQuery(MySqlCommand cmd, ref string msg) {

            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();
            
            try {

                conn.ConnectionString = ConString;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = ComTym;
                conn.Open(); // ERROR RIGHT HERE
                cmd.Connection = conn;

                var rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                conn.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                msg = ErrorMessage(ex);
            }
            finally {
                conn.Close();
            }

        }
```

btw, i read it also has something to do with windows update so I'll say my OS is windows 11, if that helps? I dont really know where this error coming from. I previously use visual studio 2013 and i never had any problem.

Comment: try upgrading that package to a recent version which is supported by .net 6 https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management/6.0.0

Comment: that solved it! put it in answers so i could mark it as answer. but i wonder why it defaulted to 4.0

Comment: @coder_b Thanks, that just resolved the same problem for me. It suddently occured and well I also updated to Windows 11 recently.