# Assembly Cannot be installed because of Existing Policy CLR

Tags: sql-server, dll, .net-assembly, sqlclr

I have written a CLR Assembly that I wish to deploy to SQL Server 2017 (14.0.3048.4). The assembly uses C# and Targets .NET Framework 4.8, which is installed on the server (Release 528049, Version 4.8.03761). I am using Visual Studio 2022 (17.8.3) to write the CLR Functions.

When I run the 'CREATE ASSEMBLY' Command from the .dll, I receive the following warning and error message:

> Warning: The Microsoft .NET Framework assembly 'system.diagnostics.tracing, version=4.2.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.' you are registering is not fully tested in the SQL Server hosted environment and is not supported. In the future, if you upgrade or service this assembly or the .NET Framework, your CLR integration routine may stop working. Please refer SQL Server Books Online for more details.

```
Msg 6586, Level 16, State 1, Line 77
Assembly 'System.Diagnostics.Tracing' could not be installed because existing policy would keep it from being used.
```

I think I understand the warning that is being given, but is it something that I actually need to worry about - I would really like to be able to deploy the CLR Project - How can I (should I?) bypass this error?

### Background

I think that I am using the latest version of `system.diagnostics.tracing`, so [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72587895/how-to-solve-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-management-version-4-0-0-0) does not apply (Although I did try different versions). I wondered whether I should be changing binding redirects as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47570912/strange-issue-with-system-net-http-4-2-0-0-not-found), but I was not confident that this would do anything and couldn't find the files I needed to update.

I think the issue may be in the usage of `ClosedXML.Excel`, since the project worked without the function that uses that, but I'm not sure that I should actually be blaming that assembly. I tried going back to version 0.97 of ClosedXML, seeing comments about stability, but that caused other issues to start cropping up, so I went back to 1.102 (latest stable) and the error mentioned above.

I have tried targeting .NET 4.7.2 in the CLR Project, but that did not help either. I also tried adding a reference to a copy of `System.Diagnostics.Tracing`, but for some reason it does not populate into the `bin/Release` folder that I copy onto the server. I have added and removed and re-added all the .dlls I could think of to the GAC.

Comment: It's not the version number. It's not a trusted assembly, so you need to give it the right permissions. See duplicate

Comment: @Charlieface I made the assembly with the dll referenced, using `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll`, but I still get the same message - I guess I should be doing the same for netstandard.dll? Do all the certificates need to be added to the same login as from the Asymmetric key used for the main assembly?

Comment: I think you need a separate `LOGIN` for each assembly but might be wrong. See also https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/08/09/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-2-clr-strict-security-solution-1/

Comment: @Charlieface - my understanding is that you don't need a separate login for each assembly providing that you can sign assemblies with the same certificate (upon which the login is based).

Comment: @BenThul I think that's correct as well if it were possible to use only certificates, but Rutzky uses assymetric keys, and I've never got clear if you can use certificates instead.

Comment: Fair enough and my mistake. But quoting the article: "Finally, the following steps are a one-time setup for the Project (and any new Projects added to this Solution) that will cause Assembly to be signed with the same Strong Name Key that was loaded into SQL Server via the steps detailed above." And those steps describe using the same strong name to sign assemblies for any project in the solution. So slightly weaker than I originally asserted, but still better than "one login per assembly". As is often the case, the reality is somewhere in the middle of two stark opposites.

Comment: @Charlieface Sorry for not updating the other answer yet and not responding sooner. Things have just been so chaotic lately . I should have time to do that tomorrow, as well as provide some additional explanation here.